# PATH points to wrong version of pip

Tags: python, pip, easy-install, anaconda

I have the anaconda distribution of python installed on my machine.  Before installing anaconda, i had pip installed.  Right now, my system uses the previous version of pip rather than the anaconda version.  In particular

```
arjuns-mbp:~ Arjun$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip

arjuns-mbp:~ Arjun$ which easy_install
/Users/Arjun/anaconda/bin/easy_install

arjuns-mbp:~ Arjun$ which python
/Users/Arjun/anaconda/bin/python
```

The result is that if i call a pip install, it won't add it to my anaconda version of python.  So far i haven't had an issue simply using easy_install to add packages to anaconda, but it would be nice to know what causes this discrepancy and how to fix it

**EDIT**

i tried using conda install pip, it doesn't work.  When I do
    conda list
pip showed up before and after a conda install

Comment: You should use a virtualenv. It'll save you a world of pain down the road.

Comment: Please use virtualenvs when installing Python packages: http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/09/16/recommended-way-for-sudo-free-installation-of-python-software-with-virtualenv/

Comment: You don't need to use virtualenv with conda. Use conda environments (and even then you don't have to; you can stick with the root environment if you want).

Comment: Why are people suggesting virtualenvs? conda environments work great, OP just needs to "conda install pip" first.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to `conda install pip`.

Answer (score 0):

pip should already come with Anaconda automatically.   How did you install Anaconda?   No matter, though, you can just conda install pip to make sure you have a version of pip that is tied to the Anaconda distribution.

From there you can create environments as much as you like to install whatever new trial-run software tools using `conda create -n env_name python pip`

Comment: I installed anaconda through the standard mac installer on their website.  Pip was on my machine before installing anaconda; my system points the anaconda versions of python, ipython, easy_isntall, etc. and my anaconda download does come with pip but for whatever reason my system defaults to the original pip installation rather than the anaconda one.  the conda instal pip doesn't quite fix this, nor does conda create